# Selenium chromedriver.exe

Tags: java, maven, selenium

As part of my project setup, I have two projects one as libraries and other as Selenium.
I have all the browser setup in libraries project with /src/main/resource having chromedriver.exe
Selenium project has all the pagefactory classes and this project has dependency on Library. 
However when i am running project on slave I am getting following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: c:\jenkins_slave10\workspace\TEST-Demos\file:\C:\Users\svc-hudson\.m2\repository\com\bskyb\automation\crm\libraries\1.1-SNAPSHOT\libraries-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\chromedriver\windows\chromedriver.exe
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:177)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:117)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:112)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:89)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:149)
        at com.abc.automation.crm.actions.BrowserSetup.openBrowserChrome(BrowserSetup.java:38)
        at com.abc.automation.crm.actions.Search.setup(Search.java:111)
        at com.abc.automation.crm.actions.Search.directorynumber(Search.java:35)
        at com.abc.automation.crm.stepdefs.Demo.i_search_for_directory_number(Demo.java:34)
```

Comment: You cannot have executable resources in a jar. You will have to pull it out before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the system property to specify the `chromedriver.exe` location?

Either start the selenium server with

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\path\to\your\chromedriver.exe
```

or

set the system property in your code:

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/path/to/your/chromedriver.exe");`

Answer (score 0):

You should not pack chromedirver on jar.

Try to add prebuild step in jenkins that will download chromdriver to your project folder in workspace and set relative path to it.

Answer (score -1):

Error is saying that the path you have specified is not correct path.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/path/Downloads/chromedriver"); // specify complete path. 
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Might be possible that chrome driver is not compatible with OS. You have to check this. You can download driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.16/
 and extract .zip file.

Answer (score -1):

Error is saying that the path you have specified is not correct.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c://jars//imp//IEDriverServer.exe"); // complete path. 
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I think you are missing specify your path with double '//' like below

```
c://jars//imp//IEDriverServer.exe
```